# Using programatically created CheckBoxes in Windows Form [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms

For example, I would like an array of checkboxes:

```
        CheckBox[] faults = new CheckBox[20];
```

Now how do I place these in my Form and link them to their array name?

Thanks.

Comment: From the comments below, it sounds like you were trying to generate controls in code that you could then manipulate in the designer. It sounds like you were expecting your runtime changes to persist in the designer after the code completed. This can be done by creating a plugin for Visual Studio that manipulates the designer, but Visual Studio doesn't retain any changes from the running of your normal code at all.

Comment: @Godeke, yes this is what I was hoping for, since I like visualizing things in the designer. But that's okay I am just adding all the checkboxes manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about that:

```
YourForm.Controls.AddRange(faults);
```

Comment: Thanks @rsenna! After adding the controls, can I interact with them in the Designer? If so how?

Comment: @Ryan R: you should not mix programmatically added controls with controls added automatically by the Visual Studio forms designer. Think of that like two separated worlds: if you wanna set their position through the designer, *add* them that way too.

Answer (score 2):

You have iterate through each checkboxes in `faults`, but keep in mind they do not overlap so, you can do like this.

**Example:**

```
int top = 0;  //used for proper positioning of controls
foreach (CheckBox cb in faults) 
{

   cb.Location =new Point(0 , top); // fixing cb for distinct position
   top +=10; 

   this.Controls.Add(cb);

}
```

Comment: Why would you want them all overlapping?

Comment: Can I manually position them in the Designer? Or do they have to be positioned programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in faults) YourForm.Controls.Add(cb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MS Visual Studio: create a small test project, add a checkbox to a form named `MyForm` using the Visual Studio designer and have a look into the generated method `InitializeComponent` in the file `MyForm.designer.cs`. This will help you to find out which properties of your checkboxes you will have to initialize. And, of course, you will see where Visual Studio places the call `this.Controls.Add(cb)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var faults = new CheckBox[20];

Point startPoint = new Point(20, 10);

for (int i = 0; i < faults.Length; i++)
{
    Controls.Add(new CheckBox()
    {
        Location = new Point(startPoint.X, 20 * i + startPoint.Y),
        Text = (i + 1).ToString()
    });
}
```

Good luck!