# Help with my simple winforms game

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I am trying to emulate the minesweeper game in winforms, just as an exercise. So far I have two classes, one called "Cell" which derives from regular button class, but has few properties of its own and a class that handles the logic (basically I made a two-dimensional array filled with objects of type "Cell" and populate it with bombs). I ran into a problem - how do I attach my array of "Cell" button controls to the form? Without re-writing everything from scratch? Both classes are unfinished obviously, it's just that I wanted to check how it would look on a form and realized that I am stuck.

Here is my Cell class

```
class Cell : Button
{
    //private GraphicsPath path;

    const int width = 20;
    const int height = 20;

    public byte Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsBomb { get; set; }

    public Cell()
    {

    }

    public Cell(int x, int y)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pevent);

        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = height;

    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        this.Text = Value.ToString();

    }
}
```

And here is my array class

```
class CellArray
{
    private int _rows = 0;
    private int _columns = 0;
    private int _bombAmount = 0;
    private Random rand;
    private Cell[,] cellMatrix;

    public CellArray(int rows, int columns, int bombAmount)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _columns = columns;
        _bombAmount = bombAmount;
        populate();
        setBombs();
    }

    private void populate()
    {
        cellMatrix = new Cell[_rows, _columns];

        for (int i = 1; i < _rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < _columns; j++)
            {
                cellMatrix[i, j] = new Cell();
                cellMatrix[i, j].IsBomb = false;

            }
        }
    }

    private void setBombs()
    {
        //*****************************************QUESTIONABLE************************************
        rand = new Random();
        int k = 1;
        while (k < _bombAmount)
        {
        Flag:
            {
                int i = rand.Next(_rows);
                int j = rand.Next(_columns);
                if (cellMatrix[i, j].IsBomb == false)
                    cellMatrix[i, j].IsBomb = true;
                else
                    goto Flag;
            }
        }
        //*****************************************QUESTIONABLE************************************

        for (int i = 1; i < _rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < _columns; j++)
            {
                if (cellMatrix[i - 1, j - 1].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i - 1, j].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i, j - 1].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i - 1, j + 1].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i, j + 1].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i + 1, j + 1].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i + 1, j].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
                if (cellMatrix[i + 1, j - 1].IsBomb == true)
                {
                    cellMatrix[i, j].Value++;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: also, you don't need the goto  in setBombs (it has no effect on the flow of the code)

Comment: Don't assign the width and height in the onpaint method, just set them once in the constructor

Comment: Asher, it does - it makes sure that if there is already a bomb in certain position it does the cycle again, to ensure that all the bombs are planted and some positions are not planted two or more times.

Comment: BTW, Asher I am still trying to process what you told me about tags, but haven't quite got it yet

Comment: i'm in the c# chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: Also, I don't see that you increase the value of k. if you do that int the 'then' part if the if statement you can avoid the goto. also, this loop currently looks like an infinite loop since you don't increase the value of k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I attach my array of "Cell"
>   button controls to the form

This issue can be solved similar to this one:

[Using programatically created CheckBoxes in Windows Form [C#]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624225/using-programatically-created-checkboxes-in-windows-form-c/5624336#5624336)

The idea is to use `YourForm.Controls.Add(...)`. Don't forget to provide proper locations for your cells/buttons within the forms coordinate system.

Of course, I would like to mention that IMHO deriving `Cell` from `Button` is a horrible design decision. Better separate your data classes (like `Cell`) completely from the GUI classes (like `Button`) and choose a technique like the one Asher suggested in his first answer (add a cell to the `Tag` property of each Button) to create a connection between Cell objects and corresponding Button objects.

Comment: Because of memory concerns or? But I end up creating the same amount of buttons either way, so why not?

Comment: @Max: there are tons of reasons why you should introduce layers (at least, a data layer and a UI layer) in almost any kind of program, and I think there is not enough room here to list them all. Let me just say this: when you choose to ignore my suggestion, don't say I have not warned you when you run into trouble later when your program evolves and you come to point where you need to have to handle pure cell data, without the "Button" properties.

Comment: Your suggestion is much appreciated and I will not ignore it :)